# What is the meaning of "Only variables should be passed by reference" in PHP?

Tags: php, database, pdo

Code:

```
public function login($email , $password){
    $stmt =$this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'password' =: password");
     $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

     $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     $count = $stmt->rowCount();

     if($count > 0) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
        header('Location : home.php');
        }else {
           return false;

        }
  }
}
```

Errors:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp8\htdocs\social\core\classes\user.php on line 18
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp8\htdocs\social\core\classes\user.php on line 19

Comment: your code is failing on way too many levels.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to submit an answer for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I started writing a new comment with some explanations before I realized that this is a rabbit hole that's way deeper than it first appears.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'll chance it.

Comment: In general it is best to submit one problem at a time, but the two errors are posing two questions (at least here).

Comment: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in. After i use your code , i have this error

Answer (score 2):

If that is your actual code, you have spaces in your named placeholder `=: password` and header `Location : home.php`, which count and using single quotes (being the wrong [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)) around the column names instead of ticks, but they're not needed anyways, since there is nothing as column names that SQL would complain about.

Note: `$user->user_id;` - the `$user` has no reference and not defined, you're looking to use `$users` here. You also have an additional closing `}` brace at the end of your code, and is unsure if you have anything else above it. If not, remove it.

**See the "edit" about the password reference.**

```
public function login($email , $password){
    $stmt =$this->pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users 
                                WHERE email = :email AND password =:password");
     $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

     $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     $count = $stmt->rowCount();

     if($count > 0) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $users->user_id;
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit; // added to prevent further execution
        }else {
           return false;

        }
  }
} // << that brace should probably not be there.
```

As stated in comments by [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson), don't use MD5. Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), since that old method is old and unsafe. When you do use that safer method, make sure that the password length is long enough to accommodate the hash.

Also make sure that the session array has value. If it doesn't, then chances are you didn't start the session using [`session_start();`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

**Edit:**

As stated in comments below, assign a variable to `md5($password)` instead of passing it as a reference.

```
$password = md5($password); // wherever this is coming from.
```

then

```
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR); // in the code above
```

Use proper error handling if you're not already doing so.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Don't forget that `$user->user_id` will fail since the result is stored in a variable called `$users`.

Comment: the Notice about 'Only variables should be passed by reference' would still be there: `$stmt->bindParam(":password", md5($password),...`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson right; that should be `$users->user_id;` with a plurarized? I think I have set myself in a rabbit hole here lol!

Comment: I might scrap my answer.

Comment: Instead of assigning the hash to a variable, I would just use `bindValue`. Also `PDO::PARAM_STR` is redundant since you're providing strings to the statement anyway, so they don't need to be converted to string. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @halfer thanks, we'll see what comes of it. If I have to find my way out of a potential rabbit hole, I'll just dump the answer *lol!*

Comment: I think I got everything, *heh*

Comment: @MagnusEriksson seeing the OP's comment under their post; yep... rabbit hole. Got a flashlight? ;-)

Comment: Hehe. Good luck! :-)

Comment: @Magnus *heh!*, yeah I might need it. and thanks ;-)